# Internet VDSL2 rate dropped Significantly after switching the ISP

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, vdsl

I get a new landline 2 months ago in order to get a VDSL2 subscription over it.

First I've subscribed with an ISP for a month and half on 70 Mbps and my line max rates was 130 Mbps Download / 65 Mbps upload.

But due to Covid-19 and its effect on the internet, My ISP was so badly effected so I decided to switch to a New one.

After Switching the line rates dropped significantly after the new ISP have connected its service immediately (as I've checked the line max rates the same day morning before they connect the service and it was 130/65).

After they called the day they have connected the service around 6 PM, I get shocked by the new line max rates which dropped to the half but for only download limit so it becomes 70 Mbps download / 65 Mbps Upload.

Their customer service is insisting on it's my issue and this is my landline defect and they can't do anything regarding this matter.

One of their technical support guys said That happens because of DLM and all things will become back to normal after 1 week!!

Finally, I really don't know what happened and why this happened and how can I solve this issue, and what is truth behind this story.

I appreciate you help :)

Comment: Only your ISP can resolve this. Note that is does take some time from an ADSL connection to "train" up to it's maximum speed and that speed depends on what equipment the ISP is using in the DSLAM (the 2 ISPs may not be using the same equipment).

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill for help, So DLM has no effect on the max rates as their technical guy said it's only effects the actual rates, am I right?

Comment: The max rate is set by the DSLAM. The actual rate depends on line length and losses. The actual rate will vary while the line "trains" and then settle down at the maximum the line can support with a specified maximum error rate.

Comment: Its also possible the pain being used is lower quality, or the ISP hardware does not support standards that are as fast (eg vectoring). In DSL questions its useful to state the country and providers, as there are different deployment strategies.

Comment: It is possible that you are in an initial line training period.  I've switched ISP lately and speeds dropped from 70 mbps down to 50 for a time. Over the course of two weeks it reset itself twice and stepped up to 58mbps then 67mbps. It has more recently settled at a solid 70mbps again. This is most likely an issue between your ISP and your landline.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, The speed today has raised to 87 Mbps, So I think it's the line training period, I'll wait for one week as the technical support advised, and then see if the connection will handle the speed I've paid for or not